# mongodb ruby delete_all nested document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I'm trying to implement a delete_all within a nested document using MongoDB Ruby-Driver. It'll be incorporated within a [bulk_write](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-bulk-operations/).

Model:

```
User
- Addresses # which is a nested model within User model
```

I can do this using Mongoid: `user.addresses.delete_all`

But I need to implement this using MongoDB Ruby Driver. I tried this but it's not working:

```
{
:update_one => {
  :filter => { "_id" => customer.id },
  :update => { "$unset" => { "addresses":{} } },
  :upsert => false 
}
}
```

I've also tried this and it doesn't work

```
{
  :update_one => {
      :filter => { "_id" => customer.id },
      :update => { "$pullAll" =>  { :addresses => [{ :category => "default"}, { :category => "work"}] }},
      :upsert => false
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it should be:

```
{
:update_one => {
  :filter => { "_id" => customer.id },
  :update => { "$set" => { "addresses":[] } },
  :upsert => false 
}
}
```